# How to upload image in web services using jsp?

Tags: mysql

> @WebService() public class
>   UrmapsDatabaseManage {
>
> private static Connection
>   getConnection() throws Exception {
>       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
>       String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dburmap";
>
> ```
> return DriverManager.getConnection(url,
> ```
>
> "root", "123");
>       }

above is my connection with mysql db..Could someone help me to do a code to insert image into my db?
Please help me :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving whole image in database you should consider uploading the image somewhere relative your webapp path and only save that path in database.